# How to change the title of iframe after file is appended?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to insert few buttons in iframe title after file is appended into iframe.But it is not working.Can someone please help me on this.

Following is the code that I am trying to do so:

```
document.getElementById("myviewer").src ="https://abc/xyz.padf";
$("#myviewer").on("load", function () {
    $('#titlebarRight').innerText = 'test';
});
```

Above is not working.Is this the right way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The contents() method returns all direct children, including text and comment nodes, of the selected element.

If you use this you'll be able to change inside the iframe.

```
document.getElementById("myviewer").src ="https://abc/xyz.padf";
$("#myviewer").on("load", function () {
    $(this).contents().find('#titlebarRight').innerText = 'test';
});
```